# AbstractNCSARequestLog not working for log4j

Tags: java, log4j, jetty

I am using Java Spark(web framework) and I am following this tutorial: http://sparkjava.com/tutorials/jetty-request-log in order to enable logging.

The following class however, gives me an error:

```
constructor AbstractNCSARequestLog in class AbstractNCSARequestLog cannot be applied to given types;
                return new AbstractNCSARequestLog() {
                       ^
  required: Writer
  found: no arguments
```

The class in question:

```
    public class RequestLogFactory {

    private Logger logger;

    public RequestLogFactory(Logger logger) {
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    AbstractNCSARequestLog create() {
        return new AbstractNCSARequestLog() {
            @Override
            protected boolean isEnabled() {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void write(String s) throws IOException {
                logger.info(s);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the old-school NCSA Request Log format, then use the 
[`Slf4jRequestLog`](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.4.26.v20200117/jetty-server/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/server/Slf4jRequestLog.java) instead of the `AbstractNCSARequestLog` (both are now deprecated).

If you want to use the modern `RequestLog` techniques use the [`CustomRequestLog`](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.4.26.v20200117/jetty-server/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/server/CustomRequestLog.java) with a [`Slf4jRequestLogWriter`](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.4.26.v20200117/jetty-server/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/server/Slf4jRequestLogWriter.java). (added bonus is the ability to customize the requestlog format)

With either of those approaches you'll need to route your slf4j to log4j (by including the `slf4j-log4j12-<ver>.jar` in your classpath)

Then you can now capture your request logs on a named logger (logger name is configurable in the `Slf4jRequestLogWriter`)

Example:

```java
Slf4jRequestLogWriter slf4jWriter = new Slf4jRequestLogWriter();
// The name of the logger to write request logs to
slf4jWriter.setLoggerName("my.requestlog");
CustomRequestLog requestLog = new CustomRequestLog(slf4jWriter, CustomRequestLog.NCSA_FORMAT);
server.setRequestLog(requestLog);
```